# Grab image url using php DOM

Tags: php, dom, thumbnails

little problem with php DOM.

```
<?php

    $url = "http://www.dogpile.com/search/images?q=" . rawurlencode($_GET['q']);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($output);
    print_r($dom->getElementById('imageResults'));

?>
```

I'm trying to get thumbnail and full image url from the results. But I cannot grab required info...

Comment: What is the output of this line `print_r($dom->getElementById('imageResults'));` ?

Comment: @sofl http://pastebin.com/wz72Ydre

Comment: How about `$images = $dom->getElementById('imageResults')->getElementsByTagName('img'); foreach($images as $image){ echo $image->getAttribute('src'); /*do stuff with src attr here...*/ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.html
```

Download library read manual and use it!